# How to solve this integral which includes Bessel function, exponential?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I need to solve the following integral $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x}\exp(-ax)\sqrt{bx^2}K_1(\sqrt{bx^2})dx$$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive constants. $K_1(x)$ is the modified bessel function of the second kind and first order. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you write $\sqrt{bx^2}$ instead of $\sqrt{b} \cdot x$?

Comment: For $a=b=1$ Mathematica gives $$\sqrt{\pi } G_{2,3}^{3,1}\left(2\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 -1,\frac{1}{2} \\
 -1,-1,1 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$ So I honestly wouldn't expect a nice closed form for general parameters. (The function is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function)